# Equivalent gcc assembly?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

What is the equivalent of the following visual studio jmp in gcc?

```
extern "C" __declspec(naked) void __stdcall Proxy_Function()
{
    __asm
    {
        jmp Procs[0];
    }
}
```

The above works just fine in visual studio.

With gcc, I tried:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall Proxy_Function()
{
    __asm("jmp *%0":: "r" (Procs[0]):);
}
```

However, my program crashes when I do that. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing `&Procs[0]` but it would help to see your C-level declaration of `Procs`

Comment: Procs is equivalent to `FARPROC Procs[10];` Then I fill in each index in the array using `GetProcAddress`. I checked to make sure they are valid of course.

Comment: `FARPROC`? Is that a normal function pointer or one of unusual size? I thought "far pointers" had died with DOS.

Comment: Its a pointer to a function in a dll. I solved it using jmp far instead of jmp. Also had to use the `&Procs[0]` like you suggestest.

Comment: @Wumpus Far was still in active use in 16 bit Windows. And for legacy reasons the terminology has persisted into 32 and 64 bit Windows, even though it now makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is most likely that gcc-for-x86 has no equivalent to `__declspec(naked)`, so the gcc-compiled code does something to the stack which it shouldn't have, causing the return from `Procs[0]` to jump to the wrong place.  I'd have to see the assembly generated for `Proxy_Function` to be sure.

I would suggest writing an `.asm` file instead of trying to shoehorn this into GCC.  On an ELF system, this would work:

```
    .text
    .globl Proxy_Function
    .type Proxy_Function,@object
Proxy_Function:
        movl Procs, %eax
        jmp *%eax
    .size Proxy_Function, .-Proxy_Function
```

However, Windows is *not* an ELF system, so the boilerplate required is different and I don't know what it is.  You can probably find out what it is by compiling

```
extern void (*Procs[10])(void);
void P(void) { Procs[0](); }
```

with `-S -O2` and inspecting the output.